# .loc returns more rows than keys

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use `.loc` to index into a `DataFrame` with 5,272 rows and 524 columns. As far as I can tell, each row is supposed to have a unique label (the `sid`).

`sid_year_data` is a dictionary whose keys are two-digit years, and whose rows are `sid`s.

```py
[ (year, len(sids)) for year, sids in sid_year_data.items() ]

>>> [(17, 844), (18, 1299), (19, 1453), (20, 1616)]

frame_data_17 = frame_data.loc[sid_year_data[17]]

frame_data_17.shape

>>> (851, 524)
```

How is it possible for indexing with 844 keys to return 851 rows? Pandas indexes are not allowed to contain duplicates, are they?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas indexes *are* allowed to contain duplicates, and in this case `frame_data`'s index had 70 duplicate items.

Answer (score 0):

The .loc method returns more rows than in the initial data frame when the argument of the .loc method has duplicates and the data frame contains rows with identical indexes but distinct values.